# Stored procedure with conditional Where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a SQL Server stored procedure. It's a simple `SELECT` query that I am building. One of the parameters is to look for a flag parameter. If that parameter is left blank, then the `SELECT` should default to NOT having the `WHERE` clause at all.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sprocA
    @flagInd int
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT intID, strQuestion, strAnswer, intCategory, intOrder
    FROM tblA 
    -- Right here is where I am looking for the logic of the @flagInd to be evaluated.....
    -- if @flagInd = 1 then 'WHERE flgInd=1' 
    -- else if @flagInd=0 then 'WHERE flgInd=0'
    -- else if @flagInd IS NULL then ''
```

It's just a simple query and a simple thought I had, not sure if it can be done without nesting and rewriting the whole `SELECT` statement as part of of the IF statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done like:

```
SELECT intID, strQuestion, strAnswer, intCategory, intOrder
FROM tblA 
WHERE flgInd = @flgInd OR @flgInd IS NULL;
```

You can also use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT intID, strQuestion, strAnswer, intCategory, intOrder
FROM tblA 
WHERE CASE 
          WHEN flgInd = @flgInd THEN 1
          WHEN @flgInd IS NULL THEN 1 
          ELSE 0
       END = 1;
```

Comment: Dont know why you add the `CASE` is complicate things.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza because in many cases it the execution plan of the first option can be less optimal than with the `CASE`  expression

Comment: I cant see that, the first one looks like can use index, can you elaborate what cases the execution will be different?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm on mobile now, but I'll try to update the question later

Comment: Ok, Let me know. Gracias.

Comment: Thank you Lamak, the CASE statement seems to really work and is exactly what I was looking for.  This makes sense and so does the execution plan.

Answer (score -1):

There appears to just be a one to one mapping (from the parameter to the column) so why not use a simple `where` clause?

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE sprocA
    @flagInd int
    AS 
    BEGIN

    SELECT intID, strQuestion, strAnswer, intCategory, intOrder
    FROM tblA WHERE flgInd = @flagInd;
```

Comment: because when `@flagInd` is `NULL` it won't return any results

Comment: Thank you Lamak, that is exactly it.  When `@flagInd` is ` NULL` it won't return any results.  Or if  `@flagInd` is blank or a space or empty and such.
Ideally, what SDSMTKyzer said would work, IF there wasn't a possibility of a `NULL` being passed. Which could be taken care of on the front side, but I want to make it so that if it is null, then there essentially would not be a filter and it would return all results.